# Appengine JDO - "managed by a different Object Manager"

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I am doing multiple job in multithreading, and I get this error when I try to fetch an entity from the datastore:

```
Object with id "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key:XXXXXXX(xxx)" is managed by a different Object Manager
```

The happen during a unit test. The problem is that I am tracking the creation of the persistence managers during the test, and I am sure that I just create *only* one using

```
JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional").getPersistenceManager()
```

If I execute the same job using only the main thread nothing happens, everything work as expected.

I read that in order to debug this, you may call `JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(object)` in order to know which persistence manager manages that object. I never get different address. 
Besides, calling this method before during the fetch sometime make the call succeed without any error.

Comment: an error has a stack trace, which tells you in turn where it comes from. Simple inspection of the code would tell you that the PM is different (either different PM, or null (transient/detached)). Nobody can see where your object(s) come from

Comment: It seems that this time it was null. 
I guess you can't share a PM among threads, you have to create new PM for each thread.

Comment: A PM is not thread-safe as per DataNucleus docs. A PMF is thread-safe